# How to hide the menu in mobile on click on the menu item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a one-page website.  I have a menu with the smooth scroll. When the user clicks on service then it will target the service section with the smooth scroll. There is no issue on the desktop.

Let's talk about mobile

In mobile, Menu is displaying like below

[image]

When I click hamburger icon then it's displaying like this
[image]

Now the issue is in the smooth scroll. When I click on service then it's targeting the service section with smooth scroll but the menu is still shown on the mobile.

I have to hide the menu when I click on the menu.

You can check my `[code here][3]`
https://jsfiddle.net/vqpyt5co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the following code to trigger click event of closing the dropdown.

```
if ($(".x_mark_img").is(":visible")) {
    $(".x_mark_img").click();
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqpyt5co/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
        if ($(".x_mark_img").is(":visible")) {
            $(".x_mark_img").click();
        }
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top-80
          }, 1000);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: if you click "services" in desktop mode the menu disappear

Comment: Oh i didnt check desktop. Let me see again.

Comment: @Fabio, Yes you are right, It's disappear the menu when click

Comment: Check the answer now please

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma, Sorry for the late reply. Give me some time to implement your code with my code.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma, Yes, It's working for me. Thanks for the help, Upvote from my side.